# Pandas column reverse the values based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda, pandas-groupby

I want to reverse the values of a column based on a condition below,i tried lambda x::-1 but it didnt 
Work as i expected.

Dataframe:

```
UserA   Order_id  reversed_id
    A         1              5
    A         2              4
    A         2.             4
    A         2.             4
    A         3.             3
    A.        4.             2
    A.        4.             2
    A.        5.             1
```

I have userA , Order_id columns and i want to generate reversed_id column,please suggest 
on this.

Answer (score 5):

We can try [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

```
df.Order_id.rank(method='dense',ascending=False)
0    5.0
1    4.0
2    4.0
3    4.0
4    3.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    1.0
Name: Order_id, dtype: float64
```